# Best way to charge this portable charger

Tags: power, charging

Hello I have a question regarding consumer electronics. Suppose I have a Li-ion portable charger. The input says USB C 5VDC 3A, 9VDC 2A. What charger would be the best to charge this charger? Would a USB-C charger that says Output: 5VDC 3A, 9VDC 2A (exact match) be the best fit? How would the device charge? Would it alternate between 5VDC 3A and 9VDC 2A? How many times would it alternate between charging ratings? Because if a different charger, a 15W USB-C charger with the single specification of 5VDC 3A was used to charge the device, how would the device charge? Would it use only the input rating of 5VDC 3A? And would that be a better charge rate to preserve the life of the battery? (Since it will charge at only 5VDC 3A , (15W)). Would the higher current degrade the battery or the higher voltage? 5V 3A would be lower voltage but higher current than the 9V 2A. So maybe a 9V 2A only charger would be better? Just wondering the best and safest way to charge this. And the way that preserves battery life. Thanks

Product is described [here](https://www.insigniaproducts.com/pdp/NS-MB27CK21/6409649)

[image]

Comment: what do you mean `charge a charger`? ... the device in each picture is a power supply, not a charger

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply, I wasnt able to post the 3rd picture of the Li-ion portable charger/power bank due to the file size being too large. The power bank's input is USB-C 5VDC 3A, 9VDC 2A. The power bank is just another term for this portable charger, which can charge a phone or laptop, etc. I am familiar with electronics but I just don't know enough about it to figure out what the optimal way to charge this is. As for the pictures I attached, how would the white one (Insignia) charge the power bank since it has the same power ratings that the power bank's input asks for, or is it unknown

Comment: **IMPORTANT** I have edited your post to show the two images that you mentioned in links. I have removed the image which did not APPEAR to relate. Please check and confirm that what I did is correct. | Your question did not seem to make sense with the old image. It makes SOME sense with the new image. More detail will be required to make the question clear.

Comment: @jsotola Please see images and my comment.

Comment: Despite what it says on the label, that's a power supply, not a charger. It will output a fixed voltage after negotiation by the attached device. The charge controller will be in the device (phone, tablet, etc.) and will regulate the voltage and current to its battery to prevent overcharge, fire and explosion.

Comment: Hi Russell, thank you and I apologize if my question wasn't as clear as it could be. The removal of the one image is fine. I included it just to provide an example of a charger that would have only one output, which is 5V 3A. The product I am inquiring about, is the Li-ion power bank, which can also be called a "portable charger". Its input reads, USB-C 5V 3A, 9V 2A. The photo above it (white Insignia plug) has the exact same output, 5V 3A, 9V 2A. For now and before trying to figure out the "best" way to charge, how would this wall adapter plug charge the power bank? (see next comment)

Comment: The wall charger (wall charger A) has the output ratings of 5V 3A, 9V 2A which matches exactly to the input ratings on the Li-ion power bank (5V 3A, 9V 2A). I'm not sure which rating would be used, or in other words, what the Li-ion power bank would call for, and what this wall charger would want to give. I thought it would alternate between ratings. But if I used a wall charger (wall charger B) with the output of ONLY 5V 3A, the Li-ion power bank would be forced to choose that input, since that is the only OUTPUT being provided by wall charger B. But for now, how would Wall charger A work?

Comment: ** IMPORTANT**  The product shown in the now single picture shown is a USB C out put "power bank" / portable power supply. It is also charged by using USB C input from any USB C capable source. ALL you need is a suitable USB C cable and a USB C capable power source. A USB 2 or USB 3 power source will also probably charge it but at lower rates of charge.

Comment: **PLEASE CONFIRM** that the sole image now shown is of the actual item concerned.  Please confirm that the other images were of suggested solutions and NOT of the target charger. (Please do NOT post images of suggested solutions).

Comment: Hi. Yes that is correct, the product in the now single picture shown is the actual item I am concerned about. The other images were indeed suggested solutions and NOT the target charger. My apologies for posting those possible solutions. Thank you for your advice about charging it with just a suitable USB C cable and USB capable power source. Not only am I concerned about the different methods of charging this "power bank" but I am also eager to learn about this kind of situation for a similar possible issue in the future and to advance my knowledge of electronics. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to simplify this.  5Vdc/3A ,9Vdc 2A are simply the specification for the technology called USB PD (power delivery). The portable device would communicate with the charger to provide the desired output, either 5V or 9V. However, one should be careful to ensure that the devices are compatible and prevent unintentional failure. Therefore, I would highly suggest that the recommended charger, as per the portable unit technical documentation is used. Otherwise, the unit may be damage, and the warranty could most likely be void.
P.S. A portable charger is a unit that is used to charge portable device and also needs to be change.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89HbU.jpg
Hi thanks,

Comment: Please see new images

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi everyone, I am using a wall adapter with USB-C 5V 3A, 9V 2A output to charge it. As Passerby has mentioned, it is most likely using the 9V 2A rating. I believe this because both the wall adapter and the power bank device have that rating. (Wall adapter has 9V 2A output, and power bank device has 9V 2A input). It is charging as I type this and the wall adapter is warm, but not hot. Thank you for all the information and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the new picture, you have a basic USB-C PD device. It can charge at 18W via 9V 2A or 15W via 5V 3A. The 18W is faster for the battery to charge from. Just use a suitable usb-c PD power supply that has 9V 2A output. They will all have a 5V out per USB standard.

The power bank will negotiate the 9V PD from the charger and will not alternate until its disconnected or the PD negotiation fails. The 5V is the fall back voltage. PD works by active communication between the source and sink.

Comment: IMages were wrong. See new images

Comment: We call it a "Power Bank". We charge our cell phones with it. In China maybe they use it as a power supply. We charge its internal battery from USB 5V. In China I do not know where they get 9V to charge it from.

Comment: @audioguru what?